# My script does not start in C#

Tags: c#, proxy

I am making a program where I need proxies for. So there is an build-in proxy scraper. It has to work fine. But it doesnt do **ANYTHING**. I dont get why it doesnt work. So that is why I am here. So, here are some things from my design:

- radioButton2 = Sets using proxies on false
- radioButton1 = Sets using proxies on true
- button1 = Starts it
- button2 = Stopts it
- Logs = An listbox (logs everything in it)

So here is my script:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Login
{
    public partial class zzz : Form
    {
        public static List<string> proxies { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> Links { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public static string path;
        public zzz()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Logs.Items.Clear();
            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                bool useproxies = true;
                Logs.Items.Add("Using proxies enabled!");
                scrape();
            }
            else
            {
                bool useproxies = false;
                Logs.Items.Add("Using proxies disabled!");
            }
            void scrape ()
            {
                int omg = proxyscraper();
                string yaas = "I found " + omg + " proxies!";
                Logs.Items.Add(yaas);
            }
        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public int proxyscraper()
        {
            void check()
            {
                string path = @"sites.txt";
                if (!File.Exists(path))
                {
                    File.Create(path).Dispose();
                    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path))
                    {
                        tw.WriteLine("http://sslproxies24.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default");
                        tw.WriteLine("https://irc-proxies24.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default");
                        tw.WriteLine("http://www.vipsocks24.net/feeds/posts/default");
                        tw.WriteLine("https://socksproxylist24.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default");
                        tw.WriteLine("https://proxyserverlist-24.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default");
                        tw.WriteLine("http://www.proxyocean.com/feeds/posts/default");
                        tw.WriteLine("https://unblockinternet.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default");
                        tw.Close();
                    }
                }

            }

            int request()
            {
                var lines = File.ReadLines(@"sites.txt");
                Logs.Items.Add("Scraping Proxies");
                Parallel.ForEach(lines, x =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var i = 0;
                        var rq = WebRequest.Create(x) as HttpWebRequest;
                        var resp = (HttpWebResponse)rq.GetResponse();
                        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            var src = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                            var regex = @"\b(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\:\d{1,6})\b";
                            var matches = Regex.Matches(src, regex);
                            Parallel.ForEach(matches.OfType<Match>(), m =>
                            {
                                i++;
                                var proxy = m.Groups[0].Value;
                                proxies.Add(proxy);
                            });
                        }
                        Func<int> temp = () => { return i; };
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    { Logs.Items.Add("" + ex);
                        Func<int> temp = () => { return 0; };
                    }
                });
                return 0;
            }
            check();
            int lol = request();
            return lol;
        }

    }
}
```

It actually goes about this part:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Logs.Items.Clear();
    if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
    {
        bool useproxies = true;
        Logs.Items.Add("Using proxies enabled!");
        scrape();
    }
    else
    {
        bool useproxies = false;
        Logs.Items.Add("Using proxies disabled!");
    }
    void scrape ()
    {
        int omg = proxyscraper();
        string yaas = "I found " + omg + " proxies!";
        Logs.Items.Add(yaas);
    }
}
```

Because it doesnt even log anything. How can I fix this? Please. I am working on this for so lon. And I am getting crazy right now.

Comment: Make sure your button is wired up to the button1_click event.

Comment: @JohnKoerner How can I get it linked?

Comment: In the designer, select the button. On the bottom right there are properties and events. On the events tab, ensure that the Click event is wired up to your method.